# How to use sshpass without TTY on a Node.JS backend?

Tags: node.js, bash, stdio, tty, sshpass

I am running the following in a script:

```
pubkey=$(gpg2 --verbose --export-ssh-key $EXPORT_THIS_ID)
sshpass -p$REMOTE_PASS ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -tt -p $REMOTE_PORT root@$REMOTE_MACHINE 'bash -s' < ./adopt-machine.sh "\"$pubkey\""
```

as a child process in node.js with `stdout` and `stderr` piped over http (no tty, hence the -tt option for the `ssh` command) and am receiving the following error:

```
Received disconnect from 172.18.0.4 port 2222:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from 172.18.0.4 port 2222
```

I've read that this error is a result of the agent attempt to connect using keys one at a time which is why I would think the error is related to tty(incorrect handling of password). Help?

EDIT: I no longer require piping stdout over http but am having the same issue. It may be unrelated to tty.

Using the ssh command without `-tt` as follows:

`result=$(sshpass -p$REMOTE_PASS ssh -vvv -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p $REMOTE_PORT root@$REMOTE_MACHINE 'bash -s' < /usr/raindrop/app/gpg/adopt-machine "\"$pubkey\""  2>&1)`

results in the following output:

```
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n 15 Mar 2022
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts'
 debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts2'
 debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
 debug2: resolving "sandbox" port 2222
 debug3: resolve_host: lookup sandbox:2222
 debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
 debug1: Connecting to sandbox [172.18.0.2] port 2222.
 debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
 debug1: Connection established.
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.8
 debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
 debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
 debug1: Authenticating to sandbox:2222 as 'root'
 debug3: put_host_port: [sandbox]:2222
 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
 debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: no algorithms matched; accept original
 debug3: send packet: type 20
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
 debug3: receive packet: type 20
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
 debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
 debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
 debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
 debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
 debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
 debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
 debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
 debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
 debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
 debug2: languages ctos: 
 debug2: languages stoc: 
 debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
 debug2: reserved 0 
 debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
 debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
 debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
 debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
 debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
 debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
 debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
 debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
 debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
 debug2: languages ctos: 
 debug2: languages stoc: 
 debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
 debug2: reserved 0 
 debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
 debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
 debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
 debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
 debug3: send packet: type 30
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
 debug3: receive packet: type 31
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
 debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:OtNG6kv5Aog+3ngJbi9PG6sLyOx2Oqjo8nGqqmCV9s4
 debug3: put_host_port: [172.18.0.2]:2222
 debug3: put_host_port: [sandbox]:2222
 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
 debug1: checking without port identifier
 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
 Warning: Permanently added '[sandbox]:2222' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
 debug1: check_host_key: hostkey not known or explicitly trusted: disabling UpdateHostkeys
 debug3: send packet: type 21
 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
 debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug3: receive packet: type 21
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
 debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa 
 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa 
 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 
 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss 
 debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
 debug3: send packet: type 5
 debug3: receive packet: type 7
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
 debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
 debug3: receive packet: type 6
 debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 debug3: send packet: type 50
 debug3: receive packet: type 51
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
 debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
 debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
 debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
 debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
 debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
 debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
 debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
 debug3: remaining preferred: password
 debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
 debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
 debug2: userauth_kbdint
 debug3: send packet: type 50
 debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
 debug3: receive packet: type 51
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
 debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
 debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
 debug3: authmethod_lookup password
 debug3: remaining preferred: 
 debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
 debug1: Next authentication method: password
 debug3: send packet: type 50
 debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
 debug3: receive packet: type 51
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
 Permission denied, please try again.
```

Similarly to what I theorized, ssh is attempting to use non existent keys in the `.ssh` directory.

Comment: It might be worth trying running the `ssh` command with the `-v` (verbose) option. If you pass `-vvv` (3x `v`s) like: `sshpass ... ssh -vvv -o IdentitiesOnly=yes ...` you should be able to see more detail on the failed attempts. Hopefully this should help you track down the cause of this issue.

Comment: @PicoutputCls Brain was fried, edited to add verbose output and new findings.

Comment: @PicoutputCls I'm thinking at this point I should ask a new question since this one was super vague to begin with.

Comment: @PicoutputCls I feel dumb, see answer... Thanks for the verbose reminder xD <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue and it had nothing to do with my code. Using `sshpass -v` I got this message:

```
SSHPASS: detected prompt, again. Wrong password. Terminating.
```

Wrong password...